# How to copy and paste in built-in dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, copy-paste, dictionary

I know how to look up words in the built-in dictionary in my iPhone, but is there some easy way to copy something from  the  dictionary or is there some 3rd party App that can do it?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn’t seem to be a way to copy from the built in dictionary, but there are workarounds.

As of recent versions of iOS, I simply take a screenshot and copy the text. Use the icon in the lower right and select text.

[image: a screenshot of my screenshot defining "screenshot"]

This works most of the time, but will not properly copy IPA.

You can also find most of the definitions (at least from NOAD and ODE) online by typing *define word* into Google/Bing. You can switch between them with these bookmarklets I made.

Switch to British English (ODE):

```
javascript:window.location=window.location.toString().includes('gl=us')?window.location.toString().replace(/gl=us/,'gl=gb'):window.location.toString()+'&gl=gb'
```

Switch to American English (NOAD):

```
javascript:window.location=window.location.toString().includes('gl=gb')?window.location.toString().replace(/gl=gb/,'gl=us'):window.location.toString()+'&gl=us'
```